# Stuctured data for weather

Tags: schema.org, structured-data

Is there structured data for weather?

I am using schema.org for my ecommerce website for various entities, like brand, products, reviews, etc. Is there something for weather forecasts?

Comment: Do you mean if there’s a weather type in the vocabulary Schema.org? Or do you want to know if there are other suitable vocabularies?

Comment: Related question on SO: [Schema.org for weather forecast](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35668427/1591669)

Answer (score 2):

For something like a Weather Forecast, you'll be best to use something like the `spatial` property in the [schema.org/Dataset](http://schema.org/Dataset) or [schema.org/Place](http://schema.org/Place).

> The range of spatial applicability of a dataset, e.g. for a dataset of
>   New York weather, the state of New York.

`datasetTimeInterval` is the unique property found in the itemtype `Dataset` which makes in perfect for something like a 7-day forecast.

Comment: Is this still the same?